# Custom Formatter Weird Behavior

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, textfield, nsformatter

I have a custom **NSFormatter** linked to 4 **NSTextFields**. When I change the values of my text fields manually, everything works fine. But when I change it through a combo box. I get an error looking like this:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc0c3
```

I've noticed that the application continuously sends this error and that the instance is always the same (**0xc0c3**). Also, when my **NSTextFields** aren't linked to my **custom formatter**, everything works well, even through the combo box.

Do you guys know what may be the source of the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Here's some code:

Combo box action:
- (void)subnetMaskByNumberOfSubnetBits:(id)sender{

```
// ------- Sets the subnet mask when the user selects the number of bits

NSNumberFormatter *stringToNumber = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];//TURN A STRING INTO A NUMBER
NSNumber *selectedAmountOfBits = [[NSNumber alloc] init];//CONTAINS THE SELECTED NUMBER OF BITS

selectedAmountOfBits = [stringToNumber numberFromString:[sender objectValueOfSelectedItem]];

[self changeSubnetMaskUsingNumberOfMaskBits:selectedAmountOfBits];

//RELEASE
[stringToNumber release];
```

}

-(void)changeSubnetMaskUsingNumberOfMaskBits:(NSNumber *)numberOfMaskBitsSelected{

```
// --------- Change the subnet mask based on the number of bits


NSInteger numberOfFullOctets;
NSInteger valueOfLastOctet;
NSInteger octetCounter;
NSMutableDictionary *subnetMaskFields = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



//Contains keys to all the outlets
[subnetMaskFields setObject:subnetMaskOctet1 forKey:@"subnetMaskField1"];
[subnetMaskFields setObject:subnetMaskOctet2 forKey:@"subnetMaskField2"];
[subnetMaskFields setObject:subnetMaskOctet3 forKey:@"subnetMaskField3"];
[subnetMaskFields setObject:subnetMaskOctet4 forKey:@"subnetMaskField4"];


//NUMBER OF FULL OCTETS AND VALUE OF LAST OCTET
numberOfFullOctets = [numberOfMaskBitsSelected intValue]/8;

valueOfLastOctet = 256 - pow(2, 8 - ([numberOfMaskBitsSelected intValue] - (8 * ([numberOfMaskBitsSelected intValue]/8)))); //Big complicated formula


//-------Setting the fields------//

//SETTING THE FIELDS OF FULL OCTETS
for (octetCounter = 1; octetCounter <= numberOfFullOctets; octetCounter++) { 
    [[subnetMaskFields objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subnetMaskField%i", octetCounter]] setStringValue:@"255"];
}

//SETTING THE FIELD OF THE INCOMPLETE OCTET
[[subnetMaskFields objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subnetMaskField%i", octetCounter]] setIntegerValue:valueOfLastOctet];


//FILLING THE ZER0S
while (octetCounter < 4) {

    octetCounter++;
    [[subnetMaskFields objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subnetMaskField%i", octetCounter]] setStringValue:@"0"];


}

//RELEASE
[subnetMaskFields release];
```

}

Comment: Usually this means that either the code is confused about what kind of object is involved, such as thinking you have a string when you really have a number, or it's a memory problem where something that used to hold a string has been released and the address is being reused for a number.  If it's always the same message and address, the first is more likely.  If you break on exceptions, do you get anything interesting in the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
[[subnetMaskFields objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subnetMaskField%i", octetCounter]] setIntegerValue:valueOfLastOctet];
```

From what I understand, since the NSFormatter needs to get the `string value` of my text field, I cannot set the text field as an integer. This line of code

```
[[subnetMaskFields objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subnetMaskField%i", octetCounter]] setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", valueOfLastOctet]];
```

solves the problem.